# Redis reverse pattern matching

Tags: redis, erlang, pattern-matching

This question may have been answered and I missed the nuances of the answers: I am trying to do a sub-query of sorts against Redis. The basic scenario is as follows:

In Redis i have a key that looks something like the following

```
dog/collie/
dog/terrier/
dog/collie/male
cat/calico/male
cat/calico/female
```

in general it can be any delimited string or any length.

The information i am using to query/sub-query is

```
dog/collie/male/black/
```

i need to query Redis and retrieve row

```
dog/collie/male
```

if the query/sub-query string is dog/collie/female/black i need to retrieve the row

```
dog/collie
```

other than pulling the rows into the application and iterating through them what is an efficient method to query these strings.

Comment: and maybe a better question is: What is a better way to solve this problem? - I am in a position to make any changes except using Erlang as the platform. 

Thank you for any help you can provide.